# Set width of div depends on x width of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my div's width expand the to the content's px. atm this is what i have:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="GameItemsImage">
    <div class="test">
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
        <img src="~/img/cd-logo.svg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.GameItemsImage {
    background-color: #3E454C;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: scroll
}

.test {
    width: 200%;
}
```

But that is static i want it to be dynamic, so that when a new item get's put in the div, it automaticly expends. How should i do that?

Comment: For dynamics functions, you have to use JavaScript (jQuery). Read the width of new div and set property to parent with css.

Comment: @JoelGeiser I'm aware that i need to user jquery. but i'm not sure where to start, can you give me a headsup, onn where to start? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.GameItemsImage {
  background-color: #3E454C;
  width: 100%;                /* (no need to add/set height) */
  overflow-x: scroll
}

.test {
  white-space: nowrap;       /* extend horizontally inline/inline-block elements */
  font-size: 0;              /* removes the 4px inline spacing */
}

/* you use images, but for textual children elements you'd want to reset font-size:1rem; */
```

```html
<div class="GameItemsImage">
  <div class="test">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x100/cf5" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x100/fc5" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x100/5fc" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x100/c5f" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x100/f5c" />
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x100/5cf" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? It's just breaks the images when it's goes to the 100% width.

`.GameItemsImage {
    background-color: #3E454C;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: scroll
}


.test img {
    float: left;
}


.test {
    overflow: auto;
}`

Comment: That worked thanks alot! But isn't it better to do with Jquery or do i only user jQuery when i can't use css?